# Go back to AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiapplicationdelegate

I am making a tab bar application. In `AppDelegate` in method **-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive** I have a string of code:

```
[self.window addSubview:pass.view];
```

So every time when app becomes active, `pass.view` appears. And when user makes all work in this view, I want to close this view and return to `AppDelegate` or any tab in the app. How do I return from `pass.view` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all you are doing is laying an UIView in top of the window, all you have to do is remove it to go "back" you can use removeFromSuperview method to achieve this.

```
[pass.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Perfect ! `[self.view removeFromSuperview]` works for me. Thank you Oscar !